# cursor.getString() doesn't work properly (ex: code postal = "01234" but return "1234" instead)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor, getstring

I'm working with Android - SQLite.
I have code postal number stored as CHAR[5] in SQLite db.

```java
Cursor cursor = db.query( ... )
String code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("code"));
```

```
CREATE TABLE codepostal (
    code CHAR( 5 ) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR( 70 ) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO [codepostal] ([code], [name]) VALUES (01001, 'My_city');
```

However it always returns with deleting "0" begining character of code postal?
(ex: code postal = "01234" but return "1234" instead)

Can someone explain?

Comment: maybe you used `putInt` to the key `code` into your `ContentValues` object?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get your answer. Can you explain it more precisely?

Comment: I supposed you used this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues) to insert "01234" into your database, but apparently you are reading from a database file, aren't you? If not, please show how you inserted "01234" into your database.

Comment: Have you checked the insert worked with the leading zero?

Comment: Possibly, you used an INTEGER datatype for the postal code instead of TEXT. So, when you save `01234`, the INTEGER `1234` is stored, instead of the TEXT `"01234"`.

Comment: I created my db by SQLite Studio then export to a sql file, then execute sql file in my Android app. Like: 
CREATE TABLE codepostal ( code CHAR( 5 ) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, name VARCHAR( 70 ) NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO [codepostal] ([code], [name]) VALUES (01001, 'My_city');

So even with CHAR[5], it still inserts my query as Int?
Thank you so much.

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai In your SQL you should have ...VALUES('01001', ...) instead of VALUES(01001, ...). Your are missing quote marks, without them SQLite converts this value to int (so without leading zero) and then saves it as varchar.

Comment: Insert the value as string literals by adding 'quote'.

Comment: Or you can use bound parameters (those funny **?** placeholders), passing a String array as the values. Android will add the necessary **'** to string values for you.

Comment: Since I makes my sql file with sqlite studio. I cant add 'quote'. Maybe I should insert data directly from csv files instead of using sqlite studio exported .sql file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All response LeoLink, Frank N. Stein, Pawel Urban, AC-OpenSource was right.
Thanks you guys so much.

Must insert the value as string literals by adding 'quote'

use

```
VALUES ('01001', 'My_city');
```

instead of

```
VALUES (01001, 'My_city');
```